# How to copy database table content from one table to another? SAP

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

i created a copy of SAP database table SFLIGHT called ZFLIGHT99, but i need to copy a data from original table too. I tried to copy by report like

```
DATA itab1 TYPE TABLE OF SFLIGHT.
DATA itab2 TYPE TABLE OF ZFLIGHT99.
itab2[] = itab1[].
```

But it doesn't work. I know that i can use loop at, but in this case i have to write all fields from this table. Is there any other solution for that?

Comment: What is the exact symptom of "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the documentation for [database insert](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapinsert_dbtab.htm). What you are doing is a copy of the internal table.
The most performant way will be `INSERT FROM SELECT` ([relevant docu](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapinsert_source.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_3@3@)). In contast to your own answer, this will not transfer data to the application server just to transfer it back to the database again. So this is more performant.

```
INSERT zpfli99 FROM ( SELECT * spfli ).
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution :)

```
DATA itab1 TYPE TABLE OF SFLIGHT.
SELECT * FROM SPFLI INTO TABLE itab1.
INSERT ZPFLI99 FROM TABLE itab1 ACCEPTING DUPLICATE KEYS.
```

Maybe someone will also look for this solution :)